# Animating Sprites issue (C++/DirectX9)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, directx

I'm working through a tutorial on animating sprites using DirectX9 and I'm doing everything correctly I just need some help on an issue that I want to correct. So far I can correctly animate the sprite, the issue is that when the sprite animates it leaves behind the image in the previous frame before drawing the next frame. How would I go about fixing this?

Here is the declaration in the header file:

```
LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 LoadTexture(string filename, D3DCOLOR transcolor = D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0));
void Sprite_Transform_Draw(LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 image, int x, int y, int width, int height, 
    int frame = 0, int columns = 1, float rotation = 0.0f, float scaling = 1.0f, 
    D3DCOLOR color = D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255,255,255));
```

Here is the definition in it's cpp file:

```
//Loads a bitmap onto a texture
LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 LoadTexture(std::string filename, D3DCOLOR transcolor)
{
    LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 texture = NULL;

    //get width and height from bitmap file
    D3DXIMAGE_INFO info;
    HRESULT result = D3DXGetImageInfoFromFile(filename.c_str(), &info);
    if (result != D3D_OK) return NULL;

    //create the new textur by loading a bitmap image file
    D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx(
        d3ddev,
        filename.c_str(),
        info.Width, info.Height,
        1,
        D3DPOOL_DEFAULT,
        D3DFMT_UNKNOWN,
        D3DPOOL_DEFAULT,
        D3DX_DEFAULT, D3DX_DEFAULT,
        transcolor,
        &info,
        NULL,
        &texture);

    //make sure the bitmap texture was loaded correctly
    if (result != D3D_OK) return NULL;

    return texture;
}

void Sprite_Transform_Draw(LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 image, int x, int y, int width, int height, 
    int frame, int columns, float rotation, float scaling, D3DCOLOR color)
{
    //Create a scale vector
    D3DXVECTOR2 scale(scaling, scaling);

    //Create a translate vector
    D3DXVECTOR2 trans(x, y);

    //Set center by dividing width and height by two
    D3DXVECTOR2 center((float)(width * scaling) / 2, (float)(height * scaling)/2);

    //Create 2D transformation matrix
    D3DXMATRIX mat;
    D3DXMatrixTransformation2D(&mat, NULL, 0, &scale, &center, rotation, &trans);

    //Tell sprite object to use the transform
    spriteobj->SetTransform( &mat );

    //Calculate frame location in source image
    int fx = (frame % columns) * width;
    int fy = (frame / columns) * height;
    RECT srcRect = {fx, fy, fx + width, fy + height};

    //draw the sprite frame
    spriteobj->Draw(image, &srcRect, NULL, NULL, color);
}
```

How I load the image in my Game_Init function:

```
bool Game_Init(HWND window)
{
    //initialize Direct3D
    if (!Direct3D_Init(window, SCREENW, SCREENH, false))
    {
        MessageBox(0, "Error initializing Direct3D", "Error", 0);
        return false;
    }

    //initialize DirectInput
    if (!DirectInput_Init(window))
    {
        MessageBox(0, "Error initializing DirectInput", "Error", 0);
        return false;
    }

    //load the sprite image
    sunflower = LoadTexture("images/Sun.bmp");
    if (!sunflower) return false;

    return true;
}
```

And how I'm drawing the image in my Game_Run function:

```
void Game_Run(HWND window)
{
    static float scale = 0.001f;
    static float r = 0;
    static float s = 1.0f;

    //make sure the Direct3D device is valid
    if (!d3ddev) return;

    //update input devices
    DirectInput_Update();

    //clear the scene
    d3ddev->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET | D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 100), 1.0f, 0);

    //start rendering
    if (d3ddev->BeginScene())
    {
        //start drawing
        spriteobj->Begin(D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND);

        //set rotation and scaling
        r = timeGetTime() / 600.0f;
        s += scale;
        if (s < 0.1 || s > 1.25f) scale *= -1;

        //draw sprite
        width = height = 64;
        frame = 0;
        columns = 1;
        color = D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255,255,255);
        Sprite_Transform_Draw(sunflower, 300, 150, width, height, frame, columns, r, s, color);

        //stop drawing
        spriteobj->End();

        //stop rendering
        d3ddev->EndScene();
        d3ddev->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }

    //escape key exits
    if (Key_Down(DIK_SPACE) || Key_Down(DIK_ESCAPE))
        gameover = true;
}

void Game_End()
{
    sunflower->Release();

    DirectInput_Shutdown();
    Direct3D_Shutdown();
}
```

Like I said everything works, it just keeps the image from the previous frame still on the screen. How would I go about clearing the screen in-between frames?

Edit:
For reference here is an image of the issue I'm trying to describe:
[image: Sprite Animation Issue]

Comment: Check the return value of `d3ddev->Clear` to see if it's failing. More generally you should be checking all return values to see if they fail.

Comment: I changed it to check for clearing the scene and no errors came up..

Comment: If you're not on Windows 8, you could use the DirectX Control Panel of the DirectX SDK to enable the debug layer of DirectX9. Often it simplifies to hunt such elemental errors down, because you get notified at invalid calls with helpful error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I didn't setup the presentation parameters correctly.

Here was the original code:

```
//set Direct3D presentation parameters
D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));
d3dpp.Windowed = (!fullscreen);
d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_COPY;
d3dpp.BackBufferCount = 1;
d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;
d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = width;
d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = height;
d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = window;
```

And here is the CORRECTLY needed code:

```
//set Direct3D presentation parameters
D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));
d3dpp.Windowed = (!fullscreen);
d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_COPY;
d3dpp.EnableAutoDepthStencil = 1;
d3dpp.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D24S8;
d3dpp.Flags = D3DPRESENTFLAG_DISCARD_DEPTHSTENCIL;
d3dpp.PresentationInterval = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_IMMEDIATE;
d3dpp.BackBufferCount = 1;
d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;
d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = width;
d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = height;
d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = window;
```